# Partial group dataframe by two conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following dataframe, where I have 3 columns (color (Yellow, Green or Red), label (A, B or C) and val(a numeric value)).

For each colour, there is 100 entries. This results in a 3 x 900 dataframe.

| col | label | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| yellow1 | A | 23 |
| yellow1 | B | 2 |
| yellow1 | C | 12 |
| green1 | A | 42 |
| green1 | B | 55 |
| green1 | C | 21 |
| yellow2 | A | 33 |
| yellow2 | B | 56 |
| yellow2 | C | 45 |

How can I change this dataframe so there is a seperate column for each colour and label. For example...

| Yellow.A | Yellow.B | Yellow.C | Green.A | Green.B | Green.C | Red.A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 2 | 12 | 42 | 55 | 21 | 64 |
| 33 | 56 | 45 | 24 | 52 | 42 | 24 |
| 23 | 2 | 232 | 53 | 32 | 24 | 112 |

Note: I do not want separate columns for Yellow1.A, Yellow2.A...etc. All 'A's for 'Yellow' should be within a single column.

I use dyplr/tidyverse as well as base.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your input data. It is obvious that something is missing in the input data. For example, there is no any values from `Red.A`.

Comment: Your data is not symetrical yet you have a 7*3 table. How did you get the table? The values in the table do not even appear in the original table

Comment: Read the text before commenting Onyambu. This is just an example table I've created manually by hand. I can't share a table with my data due to confidentiality and I do not know how to create an reproducible example of the example table. The reason it is not symetrical is because it is just a snippet of an example dataframe...not the whole example dataframe. These are simply visual aids to accompany the text.

Comment: The example tables are simply visual aids created by hand, not the actual data (the data is confidential). If the visual aids are confusing you. I can remove them.

Comment: user3200293, the reason (I believe) for the requests for consistent data is that often those providing answers use the OP's expected output to validate their attempted solution. It is not uncommon for questions to be "perfectly clear" to the asker but not as well understood by the rest of us, so when a solution we think meets the *text* of the question is different from the expected output, then we question our efforts. In this case, I have provided an answer, but my confidence in it is not high; many choose to make no attempt in this case. Ergo consistent sample data, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### base R

```r
dat$col <- sub("[0-9]+$", "", dat$col)
tmp <- lapply(split(dat, dat[c("col", "label")]), `[[`, "val")
tmp <- lapply(tmp, `length<-`, max(lengths(tmp)))
as.data.frame(tmp)
#   green.A yellow.A green.B yellow.B green.C yellow.C
# 1      42       23      55        2      21       12
# 2      NA       33      NA       56      NA       45
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(col = c("yellow1", "yellow1", "yellow1", "green1", "green1", "green1", "yellow2", "yellow2", "yellow2"), label = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), val = c(23L, 2L, 12L, 42L, 55L, 21L, 33L, 56L, 45L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```